# Delphi simple data type equivalence

Tags: delphi, reference, variable-assignment

In Delphi, if X and Y are Integers, how do I write code such that X and Y point to the same memory location?  So that if I say;

```
Y := 3;
X := 6;
write(Y);
```

the output would be 6?
As I understand it the default behavior for simple type assignments in Delphi is by value rather than by reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a variable to have the same address of another variable, use the [`absolute`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Variables_(Delphi)#Absolute_Addresses) directive:

```
var
  Y: Integer;
  X: Integer absolute Y;
..
  Y := 3;   // X = 3
  X := 6;   // Y = 6
```

Alternatively you can use pointers to be able to arbitrarily point to a memory location:

```
var
  Y: Integer;
  X: PInteger;
begin
  Y := 6;
  X := @Y;
  Write(X^);   // 6
```

Comment: @Aladdin: If you really mean pointers (references), then please read this article of mine: [Addressing pointers](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html).

Comment: FWIW, IMO, `absolute` is one of the worst constructs ever made. Worse than `with`.

Comment: @Rudy - At least it doesn't confuse the debugger, contrary to "with".

Comment: @Sertac: that's a debugger problem, not a language problem. Absolute is absolutely evil.

Comment: @Rudy - With is primarily a language problem, which confuse programmers too. The debugger is just another con with with. Without the debugger, facing the evils of the language is an absolute challenge, which is not a problem with absolute.

Comment: "Absolute" may not have some problems that "with" has, but it is still evil. It is worse than a cast and lets you do things you should not be able to do without being aware of it.